# Todays date + x days

Tags: php

I have following function:

```
$invoiceParams[2] = $invoiceDate; // dueDate
```

Where `$invoiceDate` is todays date, `$invoiceParams[2]` should be today's date + 7.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: X is a variable or fixed value as 7 ??

Comment: Please do research before posting questions like you agreed to do in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice. Also, please do not ignore the suggested questions shown to you when you are typing in your own question. What you ask for has been answered a couple hundred times before, so please use the search function to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime with date

```
$invoiceParams[2] = date('m-d-Y',strtotime(" +7 days"));
```

Comment: is there any benefit if you just add 604800 seconds to time() ?

Comment: The date would still need to be formatted. strtotime works just as well, and is easier to read.

Comment: i meant: date('m-y-Y', time() + 604800); :-)

Comment: Ah. I'm not sure if there'd be a benefit, but it'd be harder for someone to look at. With strtotime, you can see it's 7 days. If you put in 604800, someone looking at the code would have to break out the calculator to figure out how far in the future it is.

Comment: shouldn't you be adding 7 days to `$invoiceDate` rather than to `time()`?

Comment: Hah. You're right. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: You don't even need the variable `$invoiceDate` as OP says it is todays date. Sean's answer is the correct way to do it as `strtotime()` will process using todays date as 2nd argument is omitted.

Comment: Sholdt it be one more ) at the end ? :
$invoiceParams[2] = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($invoiceDate ." +7 days"));

Thanks I was not quite sure what is good solution thats why this "dumb but simple question"

Comment: Thanks, I missed the last ) in the edits. If it's today's date, then omitting $invoiceDate from strtotime will work fine.

Comment: @aynber at which point it becomes Sean's answer.

Comment: It makes it easier, since strtotime is fiddly about the date format. @cryptic I had the same answer before the edits... I took it back out. Which makes it easier, since strtotime is fiddly about the date format. It has to be d-m-Y, instead of m-d-Y.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime("+1 week"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran a quick benchmark and adding a flat number of seconds is at least twice as fast compared to parsing a `'+7 days'` or `'+1 week'` string.

```
$invoiceDate = time(); // now
$invoiceParams[2] = $invoiceDate + 604800; // +7 days

// Test
echo date('M-d, Y', $invoiceDate); // Now: Jan-03, 2013
echo date('M-d, Y', $invoiceParams[2]); // +7 days: Jan-10, 2013
```

Comment: Except that if you run it at the wrong time on the wrong day (when daylight savings shifts) you can get the wrong result and be out by a whole day